# Malware Attack?

Tags: support

Just got his message, after I had already been sitting on [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12351/send-test-email-from-sandbox) for several minutes:

[image: salesforce.stackexchange.com malware from mittenwick.com]

Very strange...

Comment: Which question were you watching?  I'm not finding that malware host anywhere...

Comment: @JarrodDixon Weird... I thought I included a link earlier. Updated the questions to include it

Comment: I couldn't get it to repeat either... but it definitely happened once

Comment: it can't be sidebar adverts, it can't be user avatars, edit history doesn't suggest any links etc... have you installed any browser plugins recently?